# How to classify overlapped signals?

Tags: machine-learning, source-separation, audio-processing, separability, signal-identification

A known signal, signal 1 got overlapped with an unknown signal. Likewise, signal 2 overlapped with another unknown signal. The problem I face now is how to classify the overlapped signals based on the signal source and label them as from signal 1 and signal 2 based on the available source training data of signal 1 and 2. Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Are you looking to classify the 'unknown' as class 3,4,5 etc? If so, how many different classes can there be? Is it finite and known up-front (closed-set classification)?

Comment: Or you just want to classify signal 1 or 2 on noisy samples?